# Why does it seem like my BACI monitor functions don't share any variables or conditions?

Tags: concurrency, c-minus-minus

I am trying to write a concurrent program that will print the letters `A` and `B` in order.
The following program looks fine and compiles, but every time I run it, it deadlocks.

```c
monitor simple_monitor { 
  int isAPrinted = 0;
  condition B_wait;

  void monitorA() { 
    isAPrinted = 1;
    cout << "A: Value of isAPrinted is now " << isAPrinted << endl;
    signalc (B_wait);
  } 

  void monitorB() {
   cout << "B: Value of isAPrinted is now " << isAPrinted << endl;
   if ( !isAPrinted ) 
      waitc( B_wait ); 
  }
} 


int main() { cobegin { monitorA(); monitorB();  } }
```

Specifically, I'm getting an error that looks like this:

```
Executing PCODE ...
A: Value of isAPrinted is now 1
B: Value of isAPrinted is now 0

BACI System: Command-line PCODE Interpreter in Java, 09:46  05 Nov 2007
Execution of process 2 aborted at loc 23
>>>Deadlock in process 2
 Process       Active Suspend  PC    xpc   atomic
 0 main             0  6000    38     0     0
 1 monitorA         0    -1     0     0     0
 2 monitorB         0  2607    23     0     0
...
```

If `monitorB` runs first, it's supposed to wait on `B_wait`, so `monitorA` can start and call `signalc(B_wait)`, waking `monitorB`. But when `monitorB` does run first, it doesn't wake up when `monitorA` finishes.

If `monitorA` runs first, it's supposed to set `isAPrinted` to 1, so `monitorB` won't wait on `B_wait`. But when `monitorA` does run first, `isAPrinted` stays 0 when `monitorB` runs!

It's like these are running in two independent execution contexts! But I can compile example programs that look just like this, and they run fine. What gives?

I am using `javabaci` as downloaded from [Dr. Tracy Camp's website](https://inside.mines.edu/%7Etcamp/baci/baci_index.html). "baci" stands for "Ben-Ari Concurrent Interpreter". It is an educational program used by some university-level operating systems courses to teach semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, in `javabaci` at least, you should not call monitor functions directly from a `cobegin()` block. Literally all you have to do is wrap the monitor function calls in another function.

So instead of

```
int main() { cobegin { monitorA(); monitorB();  } }
```

write

```
void A() { monitorA(); }
void B() { monitorB(); }
main() { cobegin { A(); B();  } }
```